# client side contour plots

Tags: javascript, html, charts, client-side, contour

Does anyone know a good resource that I can use in the browser that will handle contour plots. I am already using  [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) and have looked at [dojo's dojox/charting](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/charting.html#dojox-charting), both of which are excellent but don't give me an out of the box contour plot charting solution. Others such as [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org) also have similar limitations.

I have been largely JavaScript focused and am avoiding Flash or similar plugins, but am open to other options. I'd rather not create the images, svg, etc on the server and then use them in the client.

My main aim is to give the user some interaction with a contour plot, with clickable areas for example, and dynamic data binding, otherwise I'd probably go for the server side approach.

I've also been avoiding 3D options as this does not fit my requirements for data visualisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 allows to make some kind of contour plots: http://bl.ocks.org/4241134

Comment: Thanks Neil, that is useful, I'll take a look at try this out with my code.